# Use git hooks to create an archive of files

Tags: python, windows, git

I want to create a zip file containing some of the files in the repo, and then add and commit that as well as the files already in the repo.

I've changed `precommit` to this:

```
#!C:/Python34/python.exe

import tarfile, os
os.chdir("C:\project\directory")

with tarfile.open("archive.tar.gz", "w:gz") as f:
    for name in ["file", "names"]:
        f.add(name)
```

which creates the files, but I don't no how to add them to the commit.

I tried doing `subprocess.Popen("git add .")`, but it didn't stage the files.

Comment: "didn't seem to work" meaning...it produced an error?  Left changes staged but not committed? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the hook is called `pre-commit`, not `precommit`.

If I create a hook named `.git/hooks/pre-commit` with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import subprocess
import tarfile

print 'Adding files to archive.'
with tarfile.open("archive.tar.gz", "w:gz") as f:
    for name in ["file1", "file2"]:
        f.add(name)

print 'Adding archive to commit.'
subprocess.call(['git', 'add', 'archive.tar.gz'])
```

And add some files to the repository:

```
$ echo hello world > file1
$ echo this is a test > file2
$ git add file1 file2
```

And then commit the changes:

```
$ git commit -m "added some files"
```

I see:

```
Adding files to archive.
Adding archive to commit.
[master (root-commit) 38e33dd] added some files
 3 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 archive.tar.gz
 create mode 100644 file1
 create mode 100644 file2
```

And looking at the commit, I see:

```
$ git log -1 --name-only
commit 38e33dd5ba14d1bfe427b50cce37489259fd00c4
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@example.com>
Date:   Fri Jun 20 09:02:31 2014 -0400

    added some files

archive.tar.gz
file1
file2
```